# Home button camera

Tags: camera, home-button

On my Samsung Galaxy S7 if I press two times the home button the camera will open. 
How can I disable this function? 
Where I've to go in settings?

Comment: Does Galaxy S8 have a home button? I mean a physical one? I thought you can launch the camera by pressing two times on the power button...?

Comment: sorry, I've writed wrong in a hurry, I have a S7 ahahah

Comment: Okay. The same apply on Galaxy S7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't own a Galaxy S8 but I have the same feature on my Galaxy J5 that is called **Quick Launch Camera**.

To disable it, go to ***Settings > Advanced features > Quick Launch Camera*** and toggle it Off.

Additionally, there’s a Settings menu inside the camera app. Launch the camera and look for the gear-shaped settings button on the corner of the display. From here you can change the picture size, video quality, autofocus, ...,  and the option for Quick launch camera. Toggle it On or Off.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't remember that I had to go into Advanced Features.
I couldn't find it before!